# Does it matter if I include more references and namespaces in a class

Tags: c#

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

I have something like that in a class that I have inherited. I could remove each namespace one by one to see if the class builds, BUT does it matter?

If I am not sure if System.Xml is needed, should I remove it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**In general** all they do is add clutter.

However, they can *in some specific circumstances* cause problems with duplicate names in scope, or duplicate extension methods. For example, if there are classes `Foo.SomeType` and `Bar.SomeType`, and you have `using Foo;` and `using Bar;`, then references to `SomeType` will need disambiguating. The extension methods work similarly where static classes in different namespaces contribute conflicting extension methods.

The VS2008 tools (including express) include options to remove unnecessary `using` statements, which is very useful for tidying the code.

Answer (score 6):

In general I like to remove unused using statements as they clutter up the code.

[ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) grays out unused using statements.

[image]

It has a right click menu for, "Remove unused using statements" also.

Comment: +1 for ReSharper. It's a terrific tool (unless your solution/files are too big for it to handle, but you can try before you buy).

Comment: You right click? Keyboard shortcuts in ReSharper are so much better. Alt+Enter for the win! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using statements are only used by the compiler for type resolution so feel free to remove them if they are not needed.  Having extra will not hurt performance and removing them will only slightly improve compilation time.

Answer (score 2):

If classes with simular names exists in different namespaces it could make it harder to follow the code.

Answer (score 1):

Code tools will tell you if they are superfluous.    I would just leave them.  They don't do any harm.   (Resharper for instance)

Answer (score 1):

The unused ones will be removed on compile time so it makes no difference, don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably the definitive post on performance of using statements: [Do namespace using directives affect Assembly Loading?](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDoNamespaceUsingDirectivesAffectAssemblyLoading.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The only harm it could cause would be if two of the namespaces happened to have a class of the exact same name within it: but at that point, the IDE would warn you.

Answer (score 0):

In the past when I manually hand removed unused INCLUDEs, it had no effect on memory or speed.

As others have mentioned here, there could be collision issues but if they're all .NET classes, I wouldn't worry too much about it.